# I want to use runCommand in mongoDB while using mongoskin

Tags: node-mongodb-native, mongoskin

I want to use [`runCommand`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) in **mongoDB** while using **[mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin)**.
Currently I am doing something like this:

```
app.get('/api/powders', function(req, res, next) {
  db.collection('powders').find({} ,{limit:0, sort: [['_id',-1]]}).toArray(function(e, results){
    if (e) return next(e)
    res.send(results)
  })
})
```

it's equals to

```
db.powders.find()
```

but i want a function that will do me this

```
db.runCommand({distinct: "powders", key: "color"})
```

Can anybody help me with that or any alternative,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [db.command()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#command).

```
db.command( { distinct: "powders", key: "color" }, function( err, result ) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: can i use callback function with that?